# Run only one thread with ThreadPoolExecutor()

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I used ThreadPoolExecutor() to run multiple threads for my application. I want to take a test with single thread so I set nb_threads = 1 in this case. But I'm not sure that it's correct so can you help me take only one thread, please?

Here it's my part of code:

```
private ThreadPoolExecutor executor = null;
public static int NB_THREADS_MAX = 8;

public void submit(Runnable inRunnable) {
        if (executor == null) {

        /*Choice exactly the number of threads that relates the number of available processors*/
        nb_threads = NB_THREADS_MAX < (tmp = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
                      ? NB_THREADS_MAX
                      : tmp;
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nb_threads, nb_threads, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()); /*In this case, the pool size is fixed*/
        }

        executor.submit(inRunnable);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you make use of the factory class which expose several convenient methods?

For instance:

You can do a single threaded thread pool:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

If you check `newSingleThreadExecutor` source code you'll find this

```
 public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor() {
        return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
            (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()));
 }
```

For adding a fixed pool, with the available processors, you can do the following:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

Comment: thanks sfat, I agree that Executor is more easier than that but  I used ThreadPoolExecutor a long time now I want only to test single thread and don't want to change any things by other. And more, ThreadPoolExecutor is a sub-class of Executor :). Follow you, is my proposal correct?

Comment: @hamalo yes, it should be fine. I also edited my answer to show you the implementation of newSingleThreadExecutor and it would be the same as you want it to be, so go crazy. Although I would recomment in the future to make use of the Executors factory class since it helps a lot.

Comment: Very good! Yes, I make use of Executors factory class in the future. Thanks Sfat!